# Radio Button Selection in React Using Formik

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, formik

I have successfully selected a radio button. My problem is I want to include the selection with the label also. The labels/words should be clickable also. I'm using `Formik` by the way

Codesandbox

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-radio-button-forked-qzypk?file=/src/Radio.js)

```
   <Wrapper>
      <Item onClick={handleChecked}>
        <Button
          type="radio"
          id={name}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleChecked}
        />
        <RadioButtonLabel />
        <div>{label}</div>
        {error && touched && <TextError>{error}</TextError>}
      </Item>
    </Wrapper>
```

Comment: You will have to associate your label with the radio button. Since you are creating a `<div>` for your custom label, I think you would need to add click handler for your `<div>` to make it work like standard labels.
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#radiobutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setFieldValue` instead `handleChange` in this case: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-radio-button-forked-s261s?file=/src/index.js:250-262

In your App:

```
const {
  ...
  setFieldValue,
} = useFormik({
  ...
});

handleChange={setFieldValue}
```

In RadioButton:

```
  const handleChecked = () => {
    handleChange(name, value);
  };
```

Comment: This works with material-tailwind `Select` as well, or any other component which has its `onChange` returning a value rather than the event itself. Lifesaver! Thanks a tonne